# Send intent for screen on from shell

Tags: android, console, android-intent, screen

How can send intent in the console for start the screen on ?
I know the action for turning the screen on it is Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, but I have hard time sending the intent from console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually turn the screen on - rather it tells receivers (falsely) that the screen is being turned on.